# QuerySet object has no attribute "email"

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-queryset

I am trying to get a list of all pathologists in my system. I need to filter the user on 2 basis i-e is_pathologist and Lab_Id=request.data[email]

I have tried switching between filter and get but then I get
Authentication.models.User.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one User -- it returned 12!
[Error traceback here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6t7S.png)

This is the code of my view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def getAllPathologists(request):
    user = get_user_model().objects.get(is_pathologist=True)
        # If user exists, get the employee
    print("user is: ", user)
    pathologist = Employee.objects.get(user=user.email, Lab_Id=request.data['email'])
    pathologistSerializer = EmployeeSerializer(pathologist, many=True)
    return Response(pathologistSerializer.data)
```

This is user model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # Add additional fields here
    id = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_homesampler = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_pathologist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_lab = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,editable=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'password']
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    # Ensure that the password is hashed before saving it to the database
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser
```

This is Employee model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    CNIC = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    Lab_Id = models.ForeignKey(Lab, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

This is employee serializer

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userData = UserSerializer(read_only=True, source='user')
    email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    contact_number = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    is_homesampler = serializers.BooleanField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        # fields = " __all__"
        fields = ["CNIC", "Lab_Id", "userData",
                  "name", "contact_number", "email", "password", "is_homesampler"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("validated data = ", validated_data)
        email = validated_data.pop("email")
        password = validated_data.pop("password")
        name = validated_data.pop("name")
        contact_number = validated_data.pop("contact_number")
        is_homesampler = validated_data.pop("is_homesampler")
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            email=email, password=password, name=name, contact_number=contact_number)
        if (is_homesampler):
            user.is_homesampler = True
        else:
            user.is_pathologist = True
        user.save()

        EmployeeObj = Employee.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return EmployeeObj
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: I just did, please check it and let me know if you can help. thanks

Comment: Don't post code/errors as images.  Images are hard to work with.  Please post as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting objects and querysets conflated, `filter()` will return a queryset whereas `get()` tries to return an object. Below are the reasons for your errors:

1. The reason for your error with `filter()` is that a queryset is essentially a group of user objects. The queryset itself has no attribute `email`, but each user object within the group would. You therefore need to extract a single user from the queryset using `first()` or `last()`, for example.
2. Your error with `get()` is that your parameters are too broad and thus 12 users are returned. You need to adjust your code to handle this, it's usually done with either a `try/except` block or using the `get_object_or_404` Django shortcut. Once you successfully get the user object, you can call `user.email` without issue.